A fact about $\Pi_1$ formulas in $\mathsf{PA}$
Let $\mathop{\mathrm{Prov}}_{\mathsf{PA}}(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)$ be the formula in the first-order language of $\mathsf{PA}$ which says that $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\phi$, where $\ulcorner\phi\urcorner$ denotes the Gödel number of $\phi$, and let $\mathop{\mathrm{Con}}_{\mathsf{PA}}(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)=\lnot\mathop{\mathrm{Prov}}_{\mathsf{PA}}(\ulcorner\lnot\phi\urcorner)$.

Claim: If $\phi\in\Pi_1$, then $\mathsf{PA}+\mathop{\mathrm{Con}}_{\mathsf{PA}}(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)\vdash\phi$.

I think I can prove this along these lines: Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be the standard model of $\mathsf{PA}$. By $\Sigma_1$-completeness applied to $\lnot\phi\in\Sigma_1$, we know
$$\textstyle\mathfrak{A}\models\lnot\phi\rightarrow\mathop{\mathrm{Prov}}_{\mathsf{PA}}(\ulcorner\lnot\phi\urcorner)\tag{1}$$
Since the argument for this can be carried out in $\mathsf{PA}$, it follows that
$$\textstyle\mathsf{PA}\vdash\lnot\phi\rightarrow\mathop{\mathrm{Prov}}_{\mathsf{PA}}(\ulcorner\lnot\phi\urcorner)\tag{2}$$
so $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\mathop{\mathrm{Con}}_{\mathsf{PA}}(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)\rightarrow\phi$ by contrapositive and $\mathsf{PA}+\mathop{\mathrm{Con}}_{\mathsf{PA}}(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)\vdash\phi$ by modus ponens.
I'm fuzzy on the move from (1) to (2). Assuming it's correct, how can I more formally justify this?
I searched for similar questions on the site but may have missed one. If I did, a pointer is appreciated.

Below I suppress Godel numbering for brevity.
I think bringing in the standard model makes things less clear. The key point is that PA proves its own $\Sigma_1$-completeness, that is, for each $\Sigma_1$ sentence $\varphi$ we have $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\varphi\rightarrow\mathrm{Prov}_\mathsf{PA}(\varphi)$ (that's crucially just a one-way implication of course). Taking contrapositive of the right hand side and using the fact that the negation of a provability statement is a consistency statement, this is just $$\mathsf{PA}\vdash \mathrm{Con}_\mathsf{PA}(\neg\varphi)\rightarrow\neg\varphi,$$ whence by the deduction theorem we get $$\mathsf{PA}+\mathrm{Con}_\mathsf{PA}(\neg\varphi)\vdash\neg\varphi$$ as desired.
Now just replace "$\neg\varphi$" by "$\psi$" - if $\varphi$ is arbitrary $\Sigma_1$ then $\psi$ is arbitrary $\Pi_1$.

I believe here something stronger is needed, namely provable $\Sigma_1$-completeness for all formulae not only sentences.

Edit - No longer believe this is correct. Just leaving it up since OP does not have sufficient reputation to see deleted posts and it has a comment they may want to refer back to.

As for justifying more formally that PA proves its own $\Sigma_1$-completeness, this reduces to proving its $\Delta_0$-completeness since the argument that if $\varphi(x)$ is provable for some $x,$ then so is $\exists x\varphi(x)$ is doable in PA (though of course, how it looks exactly depends on the precise way you are encoding proofs), as is the proof of modus ponens $\operatorname{Prov}_{\sf PA}(\varphi\to\psi)\land \operatorname{Prov}_{\sf PA}(\varphi)\to \operatorname{Prov}_{\sf PA}(\psi)$, which is useful for reducing the problem to completeness for normal-form $\Sigma_1$ sentences so that the first argument suffices.
Then, observe that for $\varphi\in \Delta_0$, the statement $\varphi\to \operatorname{Prov}_{\sf PA}(\varphi)$ is $\Sigma_1$ (or more precisely, is equivalent over PA to a syntactically $\Sigma_1$ sentence), so it follows from ordinary $\Sigma_1$ completeness.

Thanks, is there any reference you can recommend which covers this result? The books that I have on hand do not.

@blargoner See Boolos. The logic of provability. Statement (61) in Chap 2, p. 46

@blargoner Actually, thinking about it, my simplification to $\Delta_0$ completeness and using $\Sigma_1$ completeness at the end does not work. What you would really need to prove in that case for $\varphi\in \Delta_0$ is that  $PA\vdash \forall x (\varphi(x) \to \operatorname{Prov}(\varphi(x)))$, which is not $\Sigma_1.$

@blargoner (however, what one can still salvage is that this formula is the sort of thing that one would prove by $\Sigma_1$-induction, which shows I$\Sigma_1$ is a sufficient fragment of PA for this to go through)
